# How do I alter Database Item templates in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like to alter the "New Stored Procedure" template in VS 2010 so that it checks for the existence of the stored proc, deletes it if it exists, then does the Create.

Where do I find that template in VS 2010? It seems like it was easy in previous versions to just alter the template.

I found a template in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items", but that is not the one the IDE is using. (That one, in fact, matches what I want to do. Probably moved over from VS 2008 during the upgrade.)

I can't find a plausible candidate under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here: [Visual Studio 2010: How to change stored procedure template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590152/visual-studio-2010-how-to-change-stored-procedure-template).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in `My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates`

Comment: No dice. I believe that is where I could publish my own templates. I'd hoped to just alter the existing template. It'd be nice to have the existing template as a reference, though, if I do need to publish my own template to the My Documents location!

Answer (score 0):

Try
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates

or

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates if you're NOT on a 64bit machine.