# Visual Studio 2010: How to change stored procedure template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, stored-procedures

How does one change the stored procedure templates for Visual Studio in 2010 2008 database projects? I've tried changing the templates in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items. This doesn't seem to affect the stored procedures created from the Add Item wizards in the database project. Am I missing something or does this method of changing stored procedure templates not work anymore? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not the exact answer you're after, but as a workaround you can edit code snippets at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Snippets\1033\Stored Procedure

When you add a new stored proc, remove the default code, right click in the code pane, and select "insert snippet".

I'll keep searching though for how to edit the new item templates though, as it's driving me nuts.

EDIT:

I kept searching, and found it:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items

Comment: That was the conclusion I had come to so far. You'd think Microsoft wouldn't remove functionality like that and not let you know how to replace it.

Comment: Found it.C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items

Answer (score 0):

create a project using the existing template.
edit it the way you want.
export the new template.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx

Comment: I am not looking for a project template. I just want to change the default new stored procedure template in VS 2010. It only includes Create Procedure and I want to add the Drop if Existing portion that VS 2008 had. I was told you used to be able to do this by changing the template file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items, but the corresponding location for VS 2010 doesn't seem to take those files into account anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2015 you will find the SQL templates in this location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items
```